# Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "responce[values]"

Tags: node.js, google-sheets, google-api, google-sheets-api, googlesheets4

I am trying to update a cell in a google sheets spreadsheet using the api with node js, and it gives me an error saying 'Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "responce[values]"'.

```js
async function setSquare(){
  let array = [['2']];
  const client = await auth.getClient();
  const googleSheets = google.sheets({version: "v4", auth: client});
  let res = await googleSheets.spreadsheets.values.update({
    auth,
    spreadsheetId,
    range: "Sheet1!B1",
    valueInputOption: "USER_ENTERED",
    responce: {values: array}
  });
}
```

This is my current code, I looked up other people's code and this seems to work fine, but for me it doesnt. When I leave the array empty it works but of course does not change anything in the spreadsheet, when I enter a value in the array it stops working and gives me this error

Answer (score 0):

### Try this:

```
async function setSquare(){
  let array = [['2']];
  const client = await auth.getClient();
  const googleSheets = google.sheets({version: "v4", auth: client});
  let res = await googleSheets.spreadsheets.values.update({
    auth,
    spreadsheetId,
    range: "Sheet1!B1",
    valueInputOption: "USER_ENTERED",
    resource: {values: array} // <-- Update
  });
}
```

Based on [this sample](https://github.com/googleworkspace/node-samples/blob/main/sheets/snippets/sheets_update_values.js) the body value that will contain the array is called `resource`.